# Subaru crosstrek, forester, impreza, outback 8 bolt valve cover tightening sequence

Tags: subaru, valve-cover, torque-specification

What is the proper torque sequence for a Subaru valve / rocker cover that has an 8 bolt pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence shown below works for the (XV) Crosstrek, Impreza, and Forester (and possibly others) if it has the 8 bolt pattern for the valve cover. Tighten in order from 1 to 8.

[image]

Good videos for reference:
https://youtu.be/nB-ls4cUkic and
https://youtu.be/evk8PNZG8c8

Comment: 4.7 lb-ft? That's like *nothing*.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular engine but these are usually shoulder bolts.  The "shoulder" contacts the cylinder head and there is often a rubber washer that provides the pressure against the cover to seal the gasket.  Greater torque does not provide greater pressure on the valve cover.  Generally you just end up stripping the threads in the head.  So these bolts often have low torque values because that's all that is needed to secure them.

Comment: @jwh20 - It would seem to me most fasteners which are attached to the engine would fairly easily vibrate free with only that amount of torque. What you said has value about the shoulder bolts and rubber washer ... just seems awfully slim to me, though.

Comment: They are shoulder bolts.  Use a 1/4" ratchet and tighten until they are firm.

Comment: Better get some idea what 4.7 ft.lb. feels like , as commented it is next to nothing. Over tightened rocker covers and pans are a common problem with beginners. The gaskets extrude and leak.

Comment: I'm familiar with shoulder bolts in valve cover usage. While it's a seemingly-trivial amount of torque, it works just fine...provided the rubber washers are in good condition.